# Store Drupal files outside of the root

Tags: files

My website is running on Windows and it sits on drive `C:/`, however I'd like to keep all my files on drive `D:/`.
How can I do it?
I know that I can move the whole site to drive `D:/` but I was wondering if it's achievable at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On linux, you could create a symlink to the other folder, or mount it over NFS etc..

On Windows you can actually create a symlink as well.

Something like this should work:

```
# Open a windows terminal and
mklink /J "C:\Webroot\Drupal\Mysite\sites\default\files" "D:\Data\Drupal\Mysite\"
```

That should create a hard link connecting the files folder across the two drives, with the data being stored on D:

More info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point

Comment: Thanks David. I'm trying to reproduce this on my local and I get `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` Can you please tell me what does it mean?

Comment: You might need to rename the current files folder first, then create the symlink. After that copy / move the files back into the new linked folder.